# all of my windows such as dope sheet, graph editor and such are completely black however the 3d viewport is completely fine

Tags: scene, performance, windows

blender update 4.0 on both browser version and steam version
[image]

Comment: Hi. Is there a chance the Rbx Animations addon has not been updated for 4.0 and that is somehow causing the problem? What happens when you disable that addon?

Comment: cant really get access to it as some windows will show but will be super stretched and glitchy which covers the button that lets me turn it off, also it thinks my mouse is way further away than it actually is. ill get back to you if i can turn off the addon in files or something

Comment: okay so ive just hopped on the steam version with a fresh file and the addon is installed but disabled, however i still have the problem.this problem only just started recently, the addon was working on update 4.0 before

Comment: Unfortunately that guess of mine is the best I can offer. This might not be relevant to your problem, but if you look at the posts at the bottom of this thread https://devforum.roblox.com/t/blender-rig-exporteranimation-importer/34729/1535 it appears that the addon has not been updated for 4.0 and some people are having various problems, although I didn't see any like yours.

Comment: Here's another idea. What happens if you do a File->Defaults->Load Factory Settings? If that fixes it, then you know there is a problem with the addon.